# .Net Entity Framework ObjectContext error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, exception, razor

I have method with code:

```
using (var cc = new MyDBContext())
            {
                var myList = (from user in cc.Users
                                   where user.UserGroup.Name == "smth"
                                   orderby user.ID ascending
                                   select user);

                if (startIndex != null)
                    return View(myList.Skip((int)startIndex).Take(50));
                else
                    return View(myList);
            }
```

In view I catch exception **The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.**

Some people says that .ToList() must solve problem, but it throws an exception with myList.ToList() too. What is my problem?

*P.S. in debug mode I have exception at @item.FullName in view, but if I move mouse on FullName property I can see correct value.*

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Possible duplicate of a million... http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ObjectContext+Disposed+%5Basp-net-mvc%5D

Comment: They advise remove using statement, but in another posts people says that I always should close dbcontext object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in lazy loaded sub property of User entity. I add to link statement Include("PropName") and it works good.

Answer (score 1):

Take the "return View()" statements outside of the "using" block completely.  That will ensure you have retrieved the complete data sets before your DbContext object is disposed.  Like this:

```
using (var cc = new MyDBContext())
{
    var myList = (linq).ToList();
}
return View(myList);
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is that you are returning an IEnumerable to the View, which means the items haven't actually been retrieved yet.  But when you return the object to your View, the DbContext is getting disposed before the view has a chance to retrieve the rows.

Comment: Updated above.  I meant to say to also include the ToList() inside the "using" block.

Comment: When I move return View(myList); outside of using statement as you say (in using statement I wrote (linq statement).ToList();) I have an exception in view @item.FullName :(.

Comment: The problem was solved with Include sub property in link statemet!